# Unchecked checkbox returns value as "undefined" via Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Jquery

```
var g = $("#chav_wc:checked").val();
alert(g);
```

and.. HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chav_wc" value="1" /></div>
```

Works fine, but if checkobx is not checked, returns value as "undefined". How can I set it to return "0" instead when not checked? Thx.

**EDIT (solution)**

Solution if someone encounters same challenge (thx 2 Dave & insertusernamehere)..

```
var g = ($('#chav_wc').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried:

```
$('#chav_wc').is(':checked');
```

Comment: var g = ($('#chav_wc').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0 ); worked.. THHHHHX! :))

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
var g = ( 'undefined' == typeof $("#chav_wc:checked").val() ? 0 : 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a function like this in my applications to simplify things.

```
function is_checked(id){
 var $check = $('#'+id);
 if($check.prop('checked')){
    return 1;
 }
 else{
    return 0;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("#chav_wc").val();` else your selector don't match the checkbox and returns undefined.

Comment: Tried that before. Keeps returning value 1 checked or not :s

Comment: So use the answer by Dave!